# How get value from adapter class to activity Class

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am having `adapter` class, In that, I need to pass `invoiceId` to an `Activity` Class. I have seen some example like pass-through interface, but I lost track on following the code procedure.

Here Is My Adapter Class extends BaseAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    companyName = ct.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    Log.d("test", "" + deliveryListBeans.size());
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ct.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_vew_for_delivery_order, null);
    TextView invoice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.invoice);
    final TextView delivery = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.do_delivery);
    final DeliveryListBean dlb = deliveryListBeans.get(position);
    invoice.setText(dlb.getInvoiceNo());
}
delivery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ct.startActivity(new Intent(ct, EmployeesListForPopUp.class));
            DeliveryOrdersListAdapter deliveryOrdersListAdapter=new DeliveryOrdersListAdapter(EmployeesListForPopUp.this);


        }
    });
}
```

Here is My Activity Class

```
public class EmployeesListForPopUp extends Activity {


private List<EmployeeIdNameBean> employeeIdNameBeans = new ArrayList<EmployeeIdNameBean>();
ListView listView;
SharedPreferences companyName;
EmployeePopUpAdapter employeePopUpAdapter;
private ImageView img1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_employees_list_for_pop_up);
```

I need to get invoiceId from Adapter Class. How?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass context of the activity in adapters constructor.

Then set activity.invoiceid value in clickevents of adapter.

Comment: public DeliveryOrdersListAdapter(Context ct, List<DeliveryListBean> deliveryListBeans) {
        this.ct = ct;
        this.deliveryListBeans = deliveryListBeans;
    }

Comment: Yes just type cast the ct.

        (EmployeesListForPopup) Ct.invoiceId

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is that you write a method in MainActivity

```
public void setInvoiceId(int invoiceId) {
    // do what you want with invoiceId
}
```

and pass the instance of your activity to adapter

```
DeliveryOrdersListAdapter adapter = new DeliveryOrdersListAdapter(EmployeesListForPopUp.this);
```

and get it in your adapter and keep it

```
EmployeesListForPopUp myActivity;

public MyAdapter(EmployeesListForPopUp activity) {
    myActivity = activity;
}
```

and where you need to pass invoiceId just call the method of main activity

```
myActivity.setInvoiceId(invoiceId);
```

Comment: Can explain how to do this with my code. `DeliveryOrdersListAdapter deliveryOrdersListAdapter=new DeliveryOrdersListAdapter(EmployeesListForPopUp.this);` I writen this in `Adapter` class and i am getting error EmployeesListForPopUp is not enclosing class

Comment: I made some edits to code plz look at the code for one more time

Comment: @aaron I edited my code. Did you write constractor for adapter with activity parameter like what I write above?

Answer (score 0):

General way of implementing it:

1. In the adapter class, where you set text to invoice TextView, you also can add a tag to it. Put attention - despite every item in the list is build from the same prototype, the tag (as well as text) will be uniq. The best way is to use "position" as value of the tag:  invoice.setText(dlb.getInvoiceNo());

invoice.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position).toString());

2. You need to make your items in the list clickable (this is out of the scope of this question). So, when you click on some item - you can retrieve any data it has, and specifically tag - getTag();.
3. Then you send Intent to other activity, providing the tag as extra message. So that activity will "know" which item in the array list it is related to (i.e. tag == position, right?). And continue from there.

I implemented simple project that illustrates it. This project is simple demo and illustration of working with ArrayList adapter,
displaying the item in the ListView, clicking on some item and display relevant data in separated activity. Please download it and try (min API 21). Basic description is available in README file.
The project is here on the GitHub:

(corrected path)

https://github.com/everall77/ArrayListSimpleExmpl

Comment: My problem is code how to apply. I read so many theories like this

Comment: Got you. Sending you very simple project illustrating the idea, in half an hour. Stay tuned.

Comment: Added example project as promised. It works. Download it and go thru the code. Ask me here if need more info clarification. Good luck!

Comment: Corrected path to the project on the GitHub